# cygwin terminal adds carriage return to bash prompt

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

Running Windows 10. Just installed Cygwin, running it in Windows Terminal, tried to change the prompt format by editing `PS1` variable and exporting in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`:

```
alias vim='nvim'
alias c='clear'
alias l='ls -altr'

export PS1='[\u \W]$ '
```

But Cygwin adds a carriage return at the end of the prompt, so the cursor always starts at the first column not at the end of the prompt. Get this error when sourcing `.bash_profile`

```
bash: $'\r': command not found
```

The carriage return does not get added when manually executing `export PS1='[\u \W]$ '` as a command.

When running `c` as defined in `.bash_profile`:

```
bash: $'clear\r': command not found
```

When running `l`:

```
ls: unknown option --
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

When running `vim` (alias):

```
bash: $'nvim\r': command not found
```

Same thing happens in the Cygwin terminal app.

Comment: How do you edit the config files? That's probably where the `$'\r'` gets added.

Comment: Do not use Windows tools to edit \*nix text files. The linked duplicate will allow you to fix your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thank you, the duplicate provided the solution, I was using windows-downloaded nvim, a simple `:set ff=unix` sufficed